# PHP - Allow 3rd Party Developers to create applications

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am currently developing a web application, everything is fine but right now I am stucked . Is there anyway on how can you use PHP to allow 3rd Party Developers to create an plugin/app for my the web application itself .. think of it like an SDK where you can allow people to create plugins for your web app ... plz Help !

Comment: This is extremely vague. We don't even know what kind of web application this is. What kind of "plugins" would developers want to create? See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn how to ask SO a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Symfony 2 framework](http://symfony.com/). The plugin concept of Symfony is called bundles. You could even use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to make sure all your bundles (=plugins) have the desired version.